# Error when upload large file

Tags: laravel, file-upload, upload, laravel-5.3

It always show `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:` when I upload large files.

I try with .zip file sizes 77MB, .mp4 file sizes 80 MB, And .zip file sizes 13MB.

I sure about CSRF field in my form.

- laravel v.5.3.29
- php 5.6.25
- apache  2.4.23

Comment: Are you submitting the form through AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change value of upload_max_filesize  in  php.ini of server to maximum size that you need .